# Insert string in regex search C#

Tags: c#, regex

How I can write this:

```
List<string> Words= new List<string>();

Regex re = new Regex(@"\b" + Words[n] + "\b");
```

My exactly question is how I can search elements from list or string using regex?

Comment: Do you mean to test each entry in the list for that expression `"\b" word "\b"`

Comment: I mean test all items from list for \b \b

Comment: So what do you want: the statement `"\b" + word "\b"` will match at anything repetition of the word. So what are you checking? That code would work for checking if the word is contained in another string?

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solution:

```
string testString = "cat and dog";
string[] Words = { "cat", "dog" };

foreach(string word in Words)
{
    bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(testString, "\\b" + word + "\\b");
}
```

Comment: I would remove the local variable `Regex re;` and call the static helper method: `bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(testString, String.Format("\b{0}\b", word))`

Comment: It should be `"\\b" + word + "\\b"`, you have to use double backslashes in regex patterns as backslash is a special character in C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use all words in one regex:

```
var words= new List<string>();
var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b(?:{0})\b", string.Join("|", words)), RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of string regex patterns:

```
List<string> words= new List<string>() { "cat", "dog" };

List<string> regexPatterns = words.Select(str => "\\b" + str + "\\b").ToList();
```

Or if you want a list of Regex objects:

```
List<Regex> regexObjects = words.Select(str => new Regex("\\b" + str + "\\b")).ToList();
```